# How would I implement functionality similar to Rails' url_for with Clojure and its web frameworks?

Tags: clojure, url-routing, ring

I'm developing a web application with Clojure, currently with [Ring](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring), [Moustache](https://github.com/cgrand/moustache), [Sandbar](https://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar) and [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup). I have a resource named *job*, and a route to show a particular step in a multi-step form for a particular job defined like this (other routes omitted for simplicity):

```
(def web-app
  (moustache/app
   ;; matches things like "/job/32/foo/bar"
   :get [["job" id & step]
         (fn [req] (web.controllers.job/show-job id step))]))
```

In the view my controller renders, there are links to other steps within the same job. At the moment, these urls are constructed by hand, e.g. `(str "/job/" id step)`. I don't like that hard-coded `"/job/"` part of the url, because it repeats what I defined in the moustache route; if I change the route I need to change my controller, which is a tighter coupling than I care for.

I know that Rails' routing system has methods to generate urls from parameters, and I wish I had similar functionality, i.e. I wish I had a function `url-for` that I could call like this:

```
(url-for :job 32 "foo" "bar")
; => "/job/32/foo/bar"
```

Is there a Clojure web framework that makes this easy? If not, what are your thoughts on how this could be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noir provides [something similar](http://webnoir.org/autodoc/1.2.1/noir.core-api.html#noir.core/url-for).  It's even called `url-for`.

Comment: Nice one! I've looked at Noir a number of times, but so far I've really liked the more minimalist approach of Moustache. I will do a little experiment today to see if Noir suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The example function you have mentioned could be implemented as below. But I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

```
(defn url-for [& rest]
    (reduce 
        #(str %1 "/" %2) "" (map #(if (keyword? %1) (name %1) (str %1)) rest)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would essentially be the same as hard-coding the url, since this function will just translate :job into "/job/".